# ¿Cómo hacer que aparezca una ventana en pantalla?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Tengo dos ventanas JFrame conectadas por medio de un boton (la segunda fue creada con la opción frame del palette)

Sin embargo al momento de abrir la segunda ventana, esta no se ve en pantalla. Supuestamente si esta abierta, pero no se ve absolutamente nada.

Es como si estuviese escondida, ¿que puedo hacer para que aparezca?

Aqui está mi codigo:

```
private void continuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      //El nombre de mi segunda ventana es pregunta2
      pregunta2.setVisible(true); this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: `private void continuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       //El nombre de mi segunda ventana es pregunta2 
        pregunta2.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
        
    } `

Comment: ¿ Puedes añadirnos el constructor de tu segundo jframe ? yo creo que puede ser que tengas que meter al final de tu constructor de tu segunda ventana: this.setVisible(true); tengo algo parecido a lo que preguntas

Comment: @Dev.Joel así lo hice pero no aparece la ventana en pantalla

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 puedes mostrarme, es que soy nueva en esto.

Comment: Necesito el codigo del constructor de tu segunda ventana así te podré ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta, dentro de lo que es el metodo **continuarActionPerformed** tienes que crear el objeto del segundo jFrame,

Primero creamos la clase del segundo JFrame:

```
public class SegundoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form SegundoJFrame
 */
public SegundoJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SegundoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SegundoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SegundoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SegundoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Y a continuación creas la clase Principal, y dentro del método del botón creas el objeto del segundo JFrame:

```
public class PrimerJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form PrimerJFrame
 */
public PrimerJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButtonEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButtonEnviar.setText("Enviar a segundo");
    jButtonEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(131, 131, 131)
            .addComponent(jButtonEnviar)
            .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButtonEnviar)
            .addGap(136, 136, 136))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButtonEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    SegundoJFrame f = new SegundoJFrame();

    f.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimerJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimerJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimerJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimerJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PrimerJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonEnviar;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Espero que te haya servido de utilidad.
Un saludo.